# Lubuntu updater popping up in Ubuntu distro

Tags: 20.04, updates, lubuntu

I don't know whether it is normal behavior, but I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 installed on my laptop and every day I am getting notification about a possible Lubuntu update. Will it change my distro? It is my company's laptop, so I don't want to do anything wrong.

I also have my screen where I unlock the disk changed from Ubuntu to Lubuntu.

My distro:

[image: My distro]

Update Notifier;

[image: Update Notifier]

Comment: The package `lubuntu-update-notifier` [https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-update-notifier] is **not** included in a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*or any other release*) install; it's created by Lubuntu for Lubuntu and is found in 'universe' & no 'universe' packages are included on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*or any release*) install ('universe' packages don't come with 5 years support) so it's not normal behavior.  You or someone with `sudo` rights must have added it to your system.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I removed that package from my system :)